# Month and Year not working in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, datetime-format

I want to get the month number and year for the next 18 months.
I have tried the following code:

```
$dat=strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
  $mnth = date('n');
  $yr=date('Y');
  echo $mnth." | " . $yr . " | " . date("Y-m-d", $dat);
  echo "<hr>";
  for($i=0; $i<=18;$i++)
  {
    echo date("n", strtotime("+1 month", $dat)) ." | ".date("Y", strtotime("+1 month", $dat)) . " | " . date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 month", $dat)) ."<br><hr>";
    $dat=date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 month", $dat));
  }
```

Code before iteration and first Iteration works fine as under:

```
8 | 2018 | 2018-08-28  
9 | 2018 | 2018-09-28
```

But all the subsequent iterations are giving following error:

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in
>   D:\Programs\PHP\aa\tdate.php on line 11
>
> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in
>   D:\Programs\PHP\aa\tdate.php on line 11
>
> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in
>   D:\Programs\PHP\aa\tdate.php on line 11 2 | 1970 |
>   1970-02-01

Please suggest some solution.

Comment: That's a painful way to accomplish this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class to accomplish this, which will be a lot easier:

```
// The actual month
$date = new DateTime(date('Y-m-') . '1');

// For the next 18 months
for ($i=0; $i < 18; $i++) {

    // Add a month to the date
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));

    // Output it as you wish:
    echo $date->format('n | Y | Y-m-d') . '<br>';
}
```

---

- [`DateTime::add()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)
- [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)
- [`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Comment: FYI, this code will break at the end of months with 31 days and February will be a problem from the 29th to the end of every month.

Comment: @JohnConde you're right. Fixed it in another way you did it.

Comment: Just realized this answer, and mine, did not give the current day of month back like the OP was looking for

Comment: Thnx, its a straightforward solution.

Comment: More or less, @Neetu. Read the comments above. As long as you don't need to use the current **date** as your output shows, then yeah, a straightforward solution.

Comment: OP was only looking for month and year, we're okay I guess

Answer (score 3):

When you try to use `date()` and `strtotime()` to manipulate dates you are using them in ways they are not really designed for.

Using [`DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) with [`DateInterval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) and [`DatePeriod()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) allows you to iterate through dates quickly and easily and *clearly*.

```
$start     = new \DateTime('first day of this month');
$end       = (new \DateTime('first day of this month'))->modify('+18 months'); 
$interval  = new \DateInterval('P1M');
$period    = new \DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
foreach ($period as $month) {
    $lastDayOfMonth = $month->format('t');
    $day = (date('d') > $lastDayOfMonth) ? $lastDayOfMonth : date('d');
    echo $month->format("n | Y | Y-m-{$day}");
    echo "\n";
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/TSn81)

Some things to keep in mind:

1. Make sure you go to the first day of the month for your start date as if you use your code with months that have 31 days it will break and February will be a problem from the 29th of each month to the end of that month.
2. If the current day is after another's month's last day you need to go back to the last day of that month. This will come into play with months that have 31 days and February every month from the 29th on.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dat=strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
for($i=0; $i<=18;$i++)
{
    echo date("n", strtotime("+".$i." month", $dat)) ." | ".date("Y", strtotime("+".$i." month", $dat)) . " | " . date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+".$i." month", $dat)) ."<br><hr>";
}
```

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Since this code is just a simplified version of the OP, I decided a lengthy explanation wasn't necessary.

Comment: But you should explain *why* and *how* this solves their problem. Just giving them working code doesn't help them, or anyone else, understand why they have a problem.